# Can't access Cookie from controller in plugin

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, controller, cookies

In the frontend my website sets a cookie wich i need during a controller action. When calling the controller action from my plugin this Cookie gets duplicated and the value is replaced with an identifier.

BEFORE CALLING CONTROLLER:
[image]

DURING CONTROLLER ACTION:
[image]

As seen in the screenshot above the original json value of the Cookie is replaces with an integer.
I have tried different methods to get the cookie but no success.

```
Cookies::$plugin->cookies->get("downloads-1") \\Returns 1649671559
Craft::$app->request->cookies->get("downloads-1") \\Returns null
$_COOKIE["downloads-1"] \\Returns 1649671559
```

How can I get the original value of my cookie in my controller?

**System** 
PHP version 7.4.16 
Craft edition & version Craft Pro 3.7.27.2

Answer (score 1):

Craft uses Yii's cookie handling, which includes [cookie validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#cookie-validation), resulting in cookies being signed with a hash string. To retrieve a plaintext (unvalidated) cookie, use PHP's global variable  `$_COOKIE`.

```php
$value = $_COOKIE['downloads-1'] ?? null;
```

From your screenshot, it looks like something unrelated created a session cookie of the same name. Look at the path to start troubleshooting where it might have been set.